# `Must declar Scalar variable at...` Can someone explain exactly what this is?

Tags: sql

Can someone help me with declaring a Scalar Variable? I really don't understand the `Scalar Variable` declaration.

Below is the code that is causing my exception.

```
int customer_Id;
int.TryParse(customer_IDTextBox1.Text, out customer_Id);

string SQL = @"UPDATE Customer
               SET Customer_Name = @customer_Name
               WHERE Customer_ID = @customer_Id";
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(SQL, sqlConnection);
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customer_Name", customer_Name);

sqlConnection.Open();
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: You add @ customer_Name, but not @ customer_id

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customer_Id", customer_Id);`line too?

Comment: The reason your question was closed is because your error is simply caused by an omission on your part. Questions/answers here are supposed to help other people in the future. Your question will not.

Comment: @LeeTaylor, I have changed the question in its entirety in an attempt to get `on topic` and regain access to ask questions again.

Comment: I didn't close your question...

Comment: @AdamWenger; Thanks for the help that you provided on my original question.  I have changed the question because the original was closed for being off topic.  I am hopping that this new question will reverse the closure.

Comment: @LeeTaylor, I realize that and I have contact as many of those that did. Thanks for the help that you did provide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only have the `@customer_Name` variable declared as a parameter.
Add the line

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customer_Id", customer_Id);
```

under your current `AddWithValue` line.

Comment: I find that odd.  It fixed my problem but why would I want to change the 'ID' column when it is already set (auto increment).  any way, thanks I appreciate the help.

Comment: I think I get it, I am not actually changing the 'ID' I am just declaring the variable.  the only change to the data table is the Customer_Name.

Comment: You are not changing the ID column, you are changing the Name column where the ID column is your input. In your code you have two code sections: The C# code that calls the SQL code. The C# code needs to supply the SQL code with all the parameters that you defined so that the SQL code can work, which in your case is requiring both the Name and ID variables. Name to change and ID to know what to change

Comment: I would like to thank you for the answer you provided above.  I have actually changed the question in its entirety in an attempt to get `on topic` and regain access to ask questions again.  Would you mind changing your answer or remove it please.

Comment: @DaveHampel, Questions should not be completely changed.  I reverted the question to the previous version, so that the question accurately reflects the comments and answers that were provided.  For your new question, please create a new question and include that information there.  Since your original question was closed, it is unlikely people were going to see your new question and take action here.

Comment: @AdamWenger, the reason i changed the previous question is because i am not allowed to ask any questions.  i have been cut off.  i have diligently tried to refrase questions to get on topic and nothing is working for me.  it truly pains me that i can't post a new question, when i conduct my searches for my topic only to find questions that i can't even understand let alone the answers.  And they can still ask question.  What would you suggest i do?  I had spent 2 hours trying to make a good question only to have you remove it.

Comment: @DaveHampel, your new problem (question) still exists in the edit history of this question, which you can copy paste out if you'd like.  Also, as that question is strongly based in SQL Server, you may find people with better information at [dba.StackExchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).  From what I was able to quickly google about your new error message, it could be: Issue with AD, empty host file,  something else.  What is the reason given for not being able to ask another question on the site? You may want to reach out to a mod to get clarification on that.

Comment: @DaveHampel Also, it will help if you add information regarding: *Whether you can still log into the original database, *Can you connect to the new database via SSMS, *Did you check the error logs on the server for anything interesting.  Also the error implies you're using Windows Auth, but you're supplying UserName/Password, so you're trying to use SQL Auth.  You can look on connectionstrings.com for what a SQL Server SQL Auth connection string should be and see if anything is out of place there.

Comment: @AdamWenger, thanks for your comments.  how do I access the edit history?  How do I find a moderator?  when I click on `Ask Question` at the top of the page it takes me to the next page and states "I have reached by limit for asking questions".

Comment: @DaveHampel, As far as question limit: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4359/is-there-a-limit-on-how-many-questions-i-can-ask says you may be getting hit if you share an IP with others also asking questions. Also, for edit history, click the text that says "Edited x time ago" to the left of your name by the question: http://screencast.com/t/gmJaJDDoa and as far as finding a mod, I believe you ask those questions in meta.stackexchange.com Good Luck!